# If the pointwise limit is uniformly continuous, the functions in the sequence need not be so

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, uniform-continuity

If $f_{n}$ is a sequence of uniformly continuous functions and $f_n \to f$, then $f$ is a continuous function.

Why is the converse of this statement not necessary true? Is there a simple example?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the relation between $f$ and $f_n$? Which precise converse do you have in mind? What are the domain of your functions?

Comment: I think you are trying to say that a uniform limit of a sequence of continuous real functions is continuous. If so, please re-write it to say so.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the functions $f_n=\chi _{[-n,n]}$. then the limit is the function $f=1$ which is continuous, but clearly $f_n$ does not converge uniformly.

Comment: What is $\chi _{[-n,n]}$?

Comment: $\chi_{[-n,n]} = \begin{cases} 
      1 & x \in [-n,n] \\
      0 & x \not \in [-n,n] \\
      
   \end{cases}
$

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful but just to make sure I fully understand this Is there an example where the intervals don't depend on $n$? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The *Cantor Function* is a good counterexample, in its alternative definition here:

[Cantor Function in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function#Alternative_definitions)

Answer (score 0):

For positive integer $n$, let $f_n(x)=0$ for $x<1/n$ and for $x>3/n.$ For  $1/n\leq x \leq 2/n$ let $f_n(x)= n^2 (x-1/n).$ For $2/n<x\leq 3/n$ let $f_n(x)=n^2 (-x+3/n).$ We have $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=0$ for every $x$, but $f_n(2/n)=n$ for every $n,$ so convergence of $(f_n)_{n\in N}$ to $0$ is not uniform.